# NSString to NSURL error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

I've made `NSStrings` into `NSURL`'s before, its always just `[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`.

Right now, I have something really weird happening. I have data (from an `NSURLSessionDataTask`) that is **not** null. As in if I print it out I get bytes of data.

Then when I try to convert it to an NSString, and log it out, it comes out as null. Really weird.

Here's a snippet:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *getProgressReportRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:curURL];
[getProgressReportRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSLog(@"The request is %@", [getProgressReportRequest URL]);

NSURLSessionDataTask *getProgressReportTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:getProgressReportRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *getProgressReportData, NSURLResponse *getProgressReportResponse, NSError *getProgressReportError) {
    if ([getProgressReportData length] > 0 && getProgressReportError == nil) {
         NSLog(@"some html is %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:getProgressReportData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    } else NSLog(@"Some error with the getting progress report %@", getProgressReportError);
}];
[getProgressReportTask resume];
```

Comment: what you are getting in console , NSLog messages?

Comment: `2014-06-05 15:36:47.767 Zangle[1613:389139] some html is (null)
2014-06-05 15:36:48.308 Zangle[1613:389139] some html is (null)
2014-06-05 15:36:48.847 Zangle[1613:389139] some html is (null)
2014-06-05 15:36:49.351 Zangle[1613:389139] some html is (null)
2014-06-05 15:36:52.629 Zangle[1613:389139] some html is (null)
2014-06-05 15:36:57.723 Zangle[1613:389139] some html is (null)`

Comment: if you can send the url , i will test it for you  & are you sure http method should be GET not POST.

Answer (score 0):

Log the data before trying to convert it to a string. Then try converting it to a string and log that.

Since you are getting non-zero-length data, I'm guessing that you are using the wrong encoding to convert it back to a string. Or maybe it's not string data at all but binary data.

Answer (score 0):

`-[NSString initWithData:encoding:]` returns nil if the data does not represent a valid string in the specified encoding. So it would appear that the data you're receiving is not valid UTF-8.